# How to pickup image load of a dynamically loaded image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, events

I am trying and failing to implement a loaded function for a dynamically loaded image.
I have the html element in the html markup first. I then have a timer that starts to fire on the jquery document ready function.  Each time the timer fires (ticks), i set the source on the html image element, and i want to know when it loads.  If it loaded correctly, i want to stop the timer.  if it didnt load correct, do nothing.

My main attempt focused on checking the natural width and height of the image node after i had set the source.  but since the code probably ran faster than the load of the image, checking the natural widht and height right after the source setting resulted in values of 0 and 0.

Should i just add a time delay between setting the image source and checking the natural width/height?
Is that the correct solution?

Here is what i have.  Notice that the loaded event never fires, but every 2 seconds i get the messages HERE and HERE2

```
<head>
...
<script>
var timer;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    timer = setInterval(function () { tick() }, 2000);
});

function tick()
{   
    alert('here');
    $('#loginTestImage').on('load', function() 
    {
        //never gets here
        alert('loaded image');
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    });
    alert('here2');

    $("#loginTestImage").attr("src", 'https://asdasd.sds.com/asdp/images/asdasd.png');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='loginTestImage'>
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to read the [Caveats of the `load` event when used with images](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) section of the jQuery documentation.

Comment: ahh caveats, hate caveats haha

Comment: You're probably hitting the cache issue.  Try appending  a nocacher like: `asdasd.png?cachebuster=" + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: ahh cachebuster, hate caches haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easy way to get image's natural size in Vanilla-js (no jQuery, I mean). 
What it does:

1. Allocate new variable for new image.
2. Set `onload` scenario. Important to do it before setting image's `src`-attribute, because once it is set the load starts.
3. Finally we set `src` which initiates image load.

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('output');

var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function() {
  cont.innerHTML = 'Error occured';
}
img.onload = function() {
  cont.innerHTML = 'Image natural height = ' + this.naturalHeight + '<br>' + 'Image natural width = ' +  this.naturalWidth;
}
img.src = 'http://brand.jquery.org/resources/jquery-dev-summit-mark.gif';
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: PS your picture link is broken @CmajSmith

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to check if the image loaded correctly or nor?

Comment: Well, it was some random image hotlinked. Gonna change it now.

Comment: About correct load. There few methods. First is `onerror` event. It fires once something happened and image wasn't loaded. Plain simple (check updated answer above). But, there may be other case, when image was loaded, but it is somehow broken, the only way to check this is to make some `if` inside `onload` that checks image height/width being `> 0`. Probably this is it.

Comment: purrrfect ! that onerror is like the greatest achievement of humans, in all of history. thanks for the help and answer !